# switching to branch, keep the old branch as it is for coming back later

Tags: git

I am working on a feature branch `branch1`, my work is not done yet and still unstable, and I need to switch back to develop branch to create a new branch, `branch2` for a new feature. How can I do that in a way to "freeze" `branch1` as I am planning to get back to work on it. Is there any way to do that without committing `branch1` ? and what's the right name for that? Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git stash is good for that (http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html)

But why do you fear commiting your changes locally? You can always edit your old commit in git or even revert it

Comment: Hi, Thanx. And once finished with `branch2`, does a simple `git checkout branch1` get me on the last state of `branch1` ?

Comment: Not 100% correct. You have to apply the stash: `git checkout branch1; git stash apply`. I prefer to use `commit --amend` or `reset` though (seems more cleaner).

Comment: Oh, okay, if you did a stash you have to re-apply it; but that is not true if you committed previously. I thought Malloc meant that case

Answer (score 3):

You can `stash` the changes, but there's no reason not to commit it.  If you don't publish the commit, you can always reset it and remove it from the history.  Using `stash` is extremely convenient, but if "later" is a long time (30+ days), it can become frustrating to find the correct stash (assuming you stash often.)  There really is nothing wrong with making a commit:

```
$ git commit -a -m "Temporary changes"
$ git checkout other-branch
$ ... # lots of work, but do not push original-branch
$ git checkout original-branch
$ git reset HEAD~  # Back to where you were with a dirty tree as modified before first commit
```

Comment: Hi, Thanx for your answer. After commit, you may forgot to stash.

Comment: You do not need to stash after the commit.  Indeed, stashing after a commit is a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

You would stash the current state of your working directory:

```
git stash
```

That will reset your working copy to the state of HEAD and save the changes since then in the repository.